# pytest brings up assertion error when using a string in the given function

Tags: python

here is my code (that is relevant to this problem)

```
# main.py
def main():
  fruit = input("What is the name of your fruit?: ")
  name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
  fruit_and_name(fruit,name)

def fruit_and_name(fruit,name):
  """
  A function that takes the name of a fruit and the user
  """

  return (f"Your name is {name} and you chose {fruit}.")

# test_main.py
from main import fruit_and_name

def test_fruit_and_name():
  assert fruit_and_name(josh, apple) == "Your name is josh and you chose apple."
  assert fruit_and_name(asd, asd) == "Your name is asd and you chose asd."
```

---

the error given:

```
____________________________________ test_fruit_and_name ____________________________________

    def test_fruit_and_name():
>     assert fruit_and_name(josh, apple) == "Your name is josh and you chose apple."
E     NameError: name 'josh' is not defined

test_main.py:8: NameError
```

---

Not sure what I'm supposed to do about this error because I can't define josh since its going into the function and its not actually a variable its just a string.

## Attempted

I've tried using "" around josh
I've also tried importing main to the test file (not sure why I thought it might work)

Anyways I'm quite lost if anyone could help thanks.

Comment: Very narrowly for your example, you need to put `josh` and `apple` in quotes

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the arguments.

```
def test_fruit_and_name():
  assert fruit_and_name("josh", "apple") == "Your name is josh and you chose apple."
  assert fruit_and_name("asd", "asd") == "Your name is asd and you chose asd."
```